# Do we need a canonical question on install types and if they hold user data?

Tags: discussion

I think we need a canonical question on install types and if they hold user data in home or otherwise (think opt or var dub dub etc) we get entirely too many questions about "will my data be gone on upgrade". I don't think we should encourage people to upgrade (I reinstall for a reason), but not everyone has a solid grasp of why deployment scripts and backup/restore scripts are so effing awesome... Anyway, thoughts?

Is there a candidate we can utilize or should we start a new one?

Comment: Hmm, Rinzwind has one about making the scripts, so that's a start.